# How to implement mouse over method?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitouch

how to implement mouse over event/method in iphone application??

Comment: more importantly, how do you connect a mouse to the iphone??

Comment: Interestingly, on jailbroken devices there are hacks that allow you to connect a bluetooth mouse. I wouldn't recommend it by any stretch of the imagination though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.

iOS has a touch based UI. There is no 'hover' or 'mouse over' event. The screen is either touched or not.